# Struggling to understand why my 'this' implementation is not working?

Tags: javascript, this

I am practicing `this` and I wrote some code.

My goal is to make `this.MemberName` become Tracey AND understand why my current attempt is not working.

When I put the object name and dot notation before the variable `assessment`, I get an error.

```js
function family(emotion) {
    return function person() { 
        console.log(
            `The core emotion that ${ this.MemberName } display's is ${ emotion }`
        );
    };
}

var tracey = {
    MemberName: "Tracey",
    age: 0,
    DOB: "29 September 2021",
};

var assessment = family("happy");
tracey.assessment();
```

Comment: `family` and `assessment` are both just functions. You expect `tracey` to have a method called `assessment` but you've never added such a method to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think you meant to set the `assessment` property of the `tracey` object.**

Your error has nothing to do with your usage of `this`, but instead the fact that you didn't set the `assessment` property before trying to call it.

**This is what your code should look like:**

```js
function family(emotion) {
    return function person() { 
        console.log(
            `The core emotion that ${ this.MemberName } display's is ${ emotion }`
        );
    };
}

var tracey = {
    MemberName: "Tracey",
    age: 0,
    DOB: "29 September 2021",
};

tracey.assessment = family("happy");
tracey.assessment();
```

Answer (score 0):

lejlun's answer is correct.

If acceptable, you could assign the property directly to the object

```js
var tracey = {
  MemberName: "Tracey",
  age: 0,
  DOB: "29 September 2021",
  assessment: function(emotion){
    console.log(
      `The core emotion that ${ this.MemberName } displays is ${ emotion }`
    );
  }
}
tracey.assessment('happy')
```

If you want to call `assessment()` on `tracey` without assigning it as a property you can pass the scope that the method `person()` should use as 'this' using [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) like below:

```js
function family(emotion) {
  return function person() { 
    console.log(
      `The core emotion that ${ this.MemberName } displays is ${ emotion }`
    );
  };
}

var tracey = {
  MemberName: "Tracey",
  age: 0,
  DOB: "29 September 2021",
};

function assessment(somePerson, emotion) {
  // family returns person()
  // we pass somePerson as 'this' to person()
  family(emotion).apply(somePerson);
}

assessment(tracey, 'happy');
```

Why your code is not working:

```js
function family(emotion) {/*...*/}
var tracey = {/*...*/};

// assessment is assigned to the global scope, 
// the same scope where family and tracey reside
var assessment = family("happy");

// we try to call a property of tracey called assessment
tracey.assessment();

// Uncaught TypeError: tracey.assessment is not a function

console.log(tracey.assessment);

// undefined
```